# How do I refer to a 'part' in a book?

Tags: bibtex, apa-style, apa6

I have a book where the content table looks like this:
PART1:
   chapter 1
   chapter 2
   chapter 3
PART2:
   chapter 4
   chapter 5
   ...
PART3:
   Appendix A
   ...

I want to reference all the chapters in PART2 (6 chapters + the conclusion chapter of this part = 7). I am using APA6 and BibTex. How do I go about this? I cannot find any information anywhere about this.

So I want it to appear like mentioned here: http://www.lib.unimelb.edu.au/recite/citations/apa6/ref08-bookChapter.html.
So it should like like this:

```
Michael, D. R., & Chen, S. L. (2005). (PART 2????). Serious games: Games that educate, train, and inform.   (45-232). Muska & Lipman/Premier-trade.
```

Currently what I have it looks like this:

```
Michael, D. R., & Chen, S. L. (2005). Serious games: Games that educate, train, and inform. Muska & Lipman/Premier-trade.
```

My bibtex looks like this:

```
@book{michael2005serious,
  title={Serious games: Games that educate, train, and inform},
  author={Michael, David R and Chen, Sandra L},
  pages={45--232},
  year={2005},
  publisher={Muska \& Lipman/Premier-Trade}
}
```

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: In principle it is better to add that kind of information through the `\cite` command, and not in the bibliography entry itself. You achieve that through `\cite[Part~2]{mybook}`. If you prefer to have it in the bibliography though, you might add `note={Part 2},` to the usual `@book` entry.

Comment: hello thanks for the help so far, I edited my question above to be more clear; adding the note={} put it all the way at the end, which is not really what I desire (or is this the only solution?)

Comment: The example in your link is valid for books in which each chapter is written by a different author. Then you should use an `@inbook` entry, with `title={},` for the title of the chapter, `booktitle={},` for the title of the book and `editor={},` for the book editors. If the whole book is written by the same authors and you want to quote a part or chapter, the standard way to do it is through the `\cite` command, as I explained above.

Answer (score 1):

It's a good old crossref situation, very easy to do.

You get your :

```
@book{michael2005serious,
title={Serious games: Games that educate, train, and inform},
author={Michael, David R and Chen, Sandra L},
year={2005},
publisher={Muska \& Lipman/Premier-Trade}
}
```

And then you add something like this :

```
@inbook{michael2005serious-chap1,
crossref={michael2005serious},
title={title},
author={author}, #Eventually
pages={x-y},
}
```

Doing so when you `\cite{michael2005serious-chap1}` bibtex retrieves the inbook entry then relates it to the book entry. You can quote a chapter and refer to the book in your biblio, your apa while style should do the proper styling.

---

Or you get the `booktitle` method which is to easy to be fun :

```
 @inbook{michael2005serious-chapter1,
 title={chaptertitle},
 booktitle={Serious games: Games that educate, train, and inform},
 editor={Michael, David R and Chen, Sandra L},
 author={chapter author},
 year={2005},
 publisher={Muska \& Lipman/Premier-Trade}
 }
```